# ActiveRecord update does not update my column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a RoR project and I'm trying to update the datetime of a column. The column I created is called "deleted_at" and the code in the controller is next:

```
def destroy
    p DateTime.now
    p Time.now.to_formatted_s(:db)
    domain = Domain.find(params[:id])
    p "RECORD: " + domain.domain.to_s
    domain.update(deleted_at: Time.now.to_formatted_s(:db))

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @domain, notice: 'Domain was successfully deleted' }
        format.js { render action: "destroy" }
    end
end
```

If I try to update another different column like the domain's name, i can do it without any kind of problem. Otherwise, updating the deleted_at column is impossible. I have tried in many different ways and i just get nothing.

This is the log from Rails console when destroy method is executed:

```
Started DELETE "/domains/28" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-06 12:56:35 +0000
Processing by DomainsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"28"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 13 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Fri, 06 Sep 2013 12:56:36 +0000
"2013-09-06 12:56:36"
  Domain Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `domains`.* FROM `domains` WHERE `domains`.`id` = 28 LIMIT 1
"RECORD: www.example.com"
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Domain Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `domains`.* FROM `domains` WHERE `domains`.`domain` = 'www.example.com' AND `domains`.`user_id` = 13 LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered domains/destroy.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 104ms (Views: 90.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

As you may see, the datetime format is correct and it is properly printed, but the update method is actually doing a SELECT instead of an UPDATE.

What's wrong my friends?

Thanks.

**EDIT** -------------------

Thanks to everyone, i found the problem (not yet the solution though). It was a validation rule. I printed the errors and i got:

```
ERROR: You already have this domain in use.
```

This message is raised by (domain.rb):

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base

    validate :domainIsUnique?

    private

    def domainIsUnique?

        if Domain.find_by domain: domain, user_id: user_id
            # Domain and user_id found, throwing error
            errors.add(:domain, "You already have this domain in use.")
        end
    end
end
```

Because of that, i can't update anything as this validation is always screwing up the process. What i don't understand is why is this validation raising itself if i'm just updating, not adding...

Comment: you say deleted_at and deleted_time  which is the column name?

Comment: also have you tried just using  domain.update_attributes(deleted_at: Time.now.to_formatted_s(:db))

Comment: My bad, the column's name is "deleted_at". I'll edit the text to fix the error. And yes, i have tried update_attributes with same result. Thanks.

Comment: I think you have a validation that failed, making the DB do a rollback.

Comment: There is not any validation about deleted_at column. It should not be affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why use a custom validation?  You should just be able to scope the uniqueness validation

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :domain, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}
end
```

Should do the same thing as your custom one.  and should work fine on the update as well.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of

since this version will ignore the record it self of update, which yours does not do, hence why you are getting the validation failed.

Answer (score 1):

I think Doon is on the right track...  Your validation will fail anytime you try to update anything because it is just searching if there is a record for a particular domain and user which there ALWAYS will be when updating, because the record you are updating itself satisfies your condition...

You could either accept Doon's solution of adding a uniqueness validation scoped to the user, or only run the validation on create.  e.g.

```
validate :domain_is_unique?, on: :create
```

Whoops, just saw your edit about it working if you update the domain...  You would expect that to work since your validation is checking for user and domain.  If you change either of those, then your "dirty" record no longer matches your validation query.

So to be clear, you would be able to update either the user or the domain, but any other update would cause the validation to fail since the query matches your current object on domain and user.

Comment: It's also useful. Thanks for the suggestion, i will keep it on mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

This should work

```
domain.update(deleted_at: Time.now.utc)
```

---

Try splitting into a manual set and then save. Update will return the class regardless of whether or not the result was saved to the database.

```
domain.deleted_at = Time.now
raise "Error saving!" unless domain.save
```

See the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class).

> Updates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.

Comment: In that case, why am i able to update the domain's name? If i make domain.update(domain: "www.example2.com") it works...

Comment: I have tried with domain.deleted_at = Time.now.to_formatted_s(:db) return "Error saving!" unless domain.save and the database doesn't change. The log keep printing a SELECT instead of an UPDATE.

Comment: What's the format then? In my MySQL domain table i have the columns created_at and updated_at, which have DATETIME format (the same in deleted_at). I can see printing all the records that the format is "Y-M-D H:M:S", the same which is shown in the Rails console by Time.now.to_formatted_s(:db)

Comment: Try it with the raise instead of the return.

Comment: This is what i get in Rails console: RuntimeError (Error saving!):
  app/controllers/domains_controller.rb:25:in `destroy'

Comment: Well if it won't save, look at domain.errors and see if there is anything in there (validation could be on a different part of the domain, that is no longer valid (IE something that should only be checked on create vs update)

Comment: Yeah. I think you can set the time variable as `Time.now` directly.

Comment: Main post updated with the problem. It was a custom validation rule... But i don't know why it is happening as i'm updating, not adding.

Comment: Validations are called before update. What you want isn't a validation, but a unique column. Add it as a migration.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update the column using following.

```
def destroy
  domain = Domain.find(params[:id])
  domain.update_attributes(deleted_at: Time.now.utc) # or Time.now
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @domain, notice: 'Domain was successfully deleted' }
    format.js { render action: "destroy" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i found the problem. It is written in the edit part of main post.